# C#: Get objects from noisy image

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have the following binary image:

[image]

The white pixels in the image are part of two objects. I need to interpolate the edges of these objects from the given white pixels.

Can someone point me in the right direction, which algorithms are usually used for these kind of problems? I can certainly think of some simple one's myself but don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: did you try simple morphological operations like closing (dilation + erosion) to make your objects more solid? do you use any image processing library?

Comment: I'm currently experimenting with AForge. The image was created by comparing color values and a given threshold. I'll take a look at the techniques you mentioned. Thank you

Comment: Morphology will indeed give useful results. But I have the feeling that other processing before binarization could do a better job. Can we see the raw image ?

Comment: Seeing the original input image would be helpful